# Amazon Alexa adding a custom utterance to an intent that would get triggered while music streaming is playing

Tags: streaming, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-interaction-model

I am currently developing an Alexa Custom Skill that need to stream a radio station. I managed to get the streaming on with `handlerInput.responseBuilder.addAudioPlayerPlayDirective('REPLACE_ALL', url, '1', 0, null, stream.metadata);` . I am now trying to trigger an intent while the streaming is on. I understood from the Amazon developer website there is a list of built-in intents that should get triggered while music is streaming. One of them being “AMAZON.RepeatIntent”, I added a custom utterance to it but when saying that phrase while the stream is playing, the intent is not triggered. The only way for it to be triggered while the stream is playing is to say “Alexa, repeat”. My question right now:

- Is there any way to add a custom utterance to an intent that would
  get triggered while Alexa is streaming music and if it is, how would
  that look. Thank you.